# Checkbox tree viewer is not displaying on composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I implemented my custom check box tree viewer, it displays simple organization hierarchy. Where organization has one (or) more managers, and each manager has one (or) more reportees under him.

```
  Organization
        Manager1
              reportee1
              reportee2
        Manager2
            reportee1
            reportee2
            reportee3
            ....
            ....
            reporteeN
```

But when I tried to add the tree viewer to the composite, it is not displaying. I am adding the code for your reference. Please let me know, where I am doing the mistake.

**Employee.java**

```
package com.sample;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private boolean inOffice;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isInOffice() {
        return inOffice;
    }

    public void setInOffice(boolean inOffice) {
        this.inOffice = inOffice;
    }

}
```

**Manager.java**

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Manager {
    private String name;
    private final List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<> ();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

}
```

**Organization.java**

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Organization {
    private String name;
    private List<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Manager> getManagers() {
        return managers;
    }

}
```

**DataUtil.java**

```
package com.sample;

public class DataUtil {

    public static Organization getOrganization() {
        Organization oranization = new Organization();
        oranization.setName("XYZ Corporation");

        Manager manager1 = new Manager();
        manager1.setName("Mukund Dixit");

        Manager manager2 = new Manager();
        manager2.setName("Anand Bandaru");

        Manager manager3 = new Manager();
        manager3.setName("Shreyas Desai");

        Manager manager4 = new Manager();
        manager4.setName("VadiRaj");

        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setInOffice(true);
        emp1.setName("Keerthi Shetty");

        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
        emp2.setInOffice(true);
        emp2.setName("Karthik");

        Employee emp3 = new Employee();
        emp3.setInOffice(true);
        emp3.setName("Brijesh");

        Employee emp4 = new Employee();
        emp4.setInOffice(true);
        emp4.setName("Deepank Bansal");

        Employee emp5 = new Employee();
        emp5.setInOffice(true);
        emp5.setName("Reshmi George");

        Employee emp6 = new Employee();
        emp6.setInOffice(true);
        emp6.setName("Janaki Sriram");

        Employee emp7 = new Employee();
        emp7.setInOffice(false);
        emp7.setName("Aravind Phaneendra");

        Employee emp8 = new Employee();
        emp8.setInOffice(true);
        emp8.setName("Nagendra");

        Employee emp9 = new Employee();
        emp9.setInOffice(true);
        emp9.setName("Maruthi");

        Employee emp10 = new Employee();
        emp10.setInOffice(true);
        emp10.setName("Piyush");

        Employee emp11 = new Employee();
        emp11.setInOffice(true);
        emp11.setName("Shanmugham");

        Employee emp12 = new Employee();
        emp12.setInOffice(false);
        emp12.setName("Phalgun Garimella");

        Employee emp13 = new Employee();
        emp13.setInOffice(false);
        emp13.setName("Sankalp");

        Employee emp14 = new Employee();
        emp14.setInOffice(false);
        emp14.setName("Arpan");

        Employee emp15 = new Employee();
        emp15.setInOffice(false);
        emp15.setName("Sandesh");

        Employee emp16 = new Employee();
        emp16.setInOffice(false);
        emp16.setName("Senthil");

        manager1.getEmployees().add(emp1);
        manager1.getEmployees().add(emp2);
        manager1.getEmployees().add(emp3);
        manager1.getEmployees().add(emp4);

        manager2.getEmployees().add(emp5);
        manager2.getEmployees().add(emp6);
        manager2.getEmployees().add(emp7);
        manager2.getEmployees().add(emp8);

        manager3.getEmployees().add(emp9);
        manager3.getEmployees().add(emp10);
        manager3.getEmployees().add(emp11);

        manager4.getEmployees().add(emp12);
        manager4.getEmployees().add(emp13);
        manager4.getEmployees().add(emp14);
        manager4.getEmployees().add(emp15);
        manager4.getEmployees().add(emp16);

        oranization.getManagers().add(manager1);
        oranization.getManagers().add(manager2);
        oranization.getManagers().add(manager3);
        oranization.getManagers().add(manager4);

        return oranization;
    }
}
```

**MyCheckBoxLabelProvider.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;

public class MyCheckBoxLabelProvider extends CellLabelProvider {

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        Object element = cell.getElement();

        if (element instanceof Organization) {
            cell.setText("Org: ");
        } else if (element instanceof Manager) {
            cell.setText("M: ");
        } else {
            cell.setText("Emp: ");
        }
    }

}
```

**MyCheckBoxTreeContentProvider.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;

public class MyCheckBoxTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    public MyCheckBoxTreeContentProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Organization) {
            return ((Organization) obj).getManagers().toArray();
        }

        if (obj instanceof Manager) {
            return ((Manager) obj).getEmployees().toArray();
        }

        return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
        Object[] roots = new Object[1];
        roots[0] = DataUtil.getOrganization();
        return roots;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Organization || obj instanceof Manager) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

**MyCheckBoxTreeSorter.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerSorter;

public class MyCheckBoxTreeSorter extends ViewerSorter {
    @Override
    public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object left, Object right) {
        if (left instanceof Manager && right instanceof Manager) {
            return ((Manager) left).getName().compareTo(((Manager) right).getName());
        }

        if (left instanceof Manager && right instanceof Manager) {
            return ((Employee) left).getName().compareTo(((Employee) right).getName());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

**MyCheckBoxTreeViewer.java**

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckStateChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CheckboxTreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ICheckStateListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ICheckStateProvider;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget;

public class MyCheckBoxTreeViewer extends CheckboxTreeViewer implements ICheckStateListener, ICheckStateProvider {
    public MyCheckBoxTreeViewer(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(this);
        initializeTree();
    }

    private void initializeTree() {
        setCheckStateProvider(this);
        addCheckStateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Manager) {
            Manager manager = (Manager) obj;

            List<Employee> employees = manager.getEmployees();
            for (Employee emp : employees) {
                if (!emp.isInOffice()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGrayed(Object obj) {
        int totalEmpsInOffice = 0;

        if (obj instanceof Manager) {
            Manager manager = (Manager) obj;

            List<Employee> employees = manager.getEmployees();
            for (Employee emp : employees) {
                if (emp.isInOffice())
                    totalEmpsInOffice++;
            }

            if (totalEmpsInOffice == employees.size()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
        Object element = event.getElement();

        Widget item = findItem(element);

        if (!(item instanceof TreeItem)) {
            System.out.println("Given item is not an instance of tree item");
            return;
        }

        TreeItem treeItem = (TreeItem) item;
        Object obj = treeItem.getData();

        if (obj instanceof Manager) {
            System.out.println("State is changed for " + ((Manager) obj).getName());
        }

        if (obj instanceof Employee) {
            System.out.println("State is changed for " + ((Employee) obj).getName());
        }

    }

}
```

**TestTreeViewer.java**

```
package com.sample;

import org.eclipse.jface.layout.GridDataFactory;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TestTreeViewer {
    private static int shellWidth = 600;
    private static int shellHeight = 600;

    private static int compositeWidth = 500;
    private static int compositeHeight = 250;

    private static void addWidgetsToShell(Display display, Shell shell) {

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setBackground(new Color(display, 102, 153, 153));
        composite.setBounds(10, 10, compositeWidth, compositeHeight);

        MyCheckBoxTreeContentProvider contentProvider = new MyCheckBoxTreeContentProvider();
        MyCheckBoxLabelProvider labelProvider = new MyCheckBoxLabelProvider();
        MyCheckBoxTreeSorter sorter = new MyCheckBoxTreeSorter();

        MyCheckBoxTreeViewer treeViewer = new MyCheckBoxTreeViewer(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(treeViewer.getTree());
        treeViewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
        treeViewer.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
        treeViewer.setSorter(sorter);
        //treeViewer.setInput("root");
        treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(2);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Instantiate Display object, it represents SWT session */
        Display display = new Display();

        /*
         * Define Shell, it represent a window, You can add more than one shell
         * to Display
         */
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(shellWidth, shellHeight);

        addWidgetsToShell(display, shell);

        /* Open shell window */
        shell.open();

        /*
         * Run the event dispatching loop until an exit condition occurs, which
         * is typically when the main shell window is closed by the user.
         */

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        /* Dispose the display */
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

I debugged, but unable to find the problem/solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.

You are not calling the viewer `setInput` method - nothing happens until you call this.

The parent of the checkbox is the Shell not the Composite you create. You are using `GridData` for the checkbox layout data but you have not set a layout for the Shell or the Composite. If you use layout data you must set a layout.

You are mixing `setBounds` and layouts - don't do this, it doesn't work.

You must call `setAutoExpandLevel` before you call `setInput`.

So for the Shell do something like:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setSize(shellWidth, shellHeight);
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

For the composite:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
composite.setBackground(new Color(shell.getDisplay(), 102, 153, 153));
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().hint(compositeWidth, compositeHeight).applyTo(composite);
```

For the checkbox:

```
MyCheckBoxTreeViewer treeViewer = new MyCheckBoxTreeViewer(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(treeViewer.getTree());
treeViewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
treeViewer.setSorter(sorter);
treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(2); 
treeViewer.setInput("root");
```

Comment: Remember to `dispose()` of the `Color` as well.